# Why can't i send two mails in a row with c#?

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient

I am sending emails using c# using SmtpClient. I have to send aproximately one hundred different emails per day, and I can't use the same mail (adding several recipients) since the email changes according to the recipient.

I am not using a local SMTP server, and I understand (according to @rizzle response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c-sharp))
that some time has to be left between one mail and another one. However, I am sleeping my program for 10 seconds and still, it is only the first email that gets sent, never the second one (so far I am trying my system with two emails instead of one hundred). This is my code, any ideas?

```
foreach (Person p in clientList)
            {
                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Texto visible para clientes que no tienen HTML", null, "text/plain");
                //AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");

                string htmlString = "html string body of the email";
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlString, null, "text/html");

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
                message.To.Add(p.email.Trim());
                message.Subject = p.nombre+", email subject";
                message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddress);
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("...");
                NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential(usr, pass, "");
                client.Credentials = myCreds;
                client.Send(message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

            }
```

Comment: How long do you have to sleep before 2 can be sent?

Comment: Could you include some more code, such as the loop you are using the send within - and any error messages you are getting

Comment: @Andrew I just included the complete loop code.

Comment: @Bali C , not sure I quite get what you're asking... I haven't been able to send both emails, tried sleeping for 10s and since that didn't work, I realized there had to be another workaround for this.

Comment: @Soph I just meant would it allow you to send both emails after say 30seconds or a minute, just to debug it a bit, but the answers below look like they might be what your after.

Comment: @Soph I don't know why you have -3, its a good question! +1

Comment: @BaliC I was wondering the exact same thing! Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `client.Dispose()` right after you send your last message, if you're on dotnet 4.  This will force the dotnet SMTP stuff to finish its work.

See here:  [System.Net.Mail and MailMessage not Sending Messages Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403599/system-net-mail-and-mailmessage-not-sending-messages-immediately/7404239#7404239)

If you're on earlier versions of DotNet, try doing a couple of things.

Do  `message.Dispose()` when you're done with the message instance.

Define your SmtpClient locally (within a method) and exit the method when you're done sending.  That is, don't try to keep your client instance around as a field in one of your long-lived class instances; it won't flush the last message you sent to the server until it's finalized.

(They really did fix this in dotnet 4.0)

Comment: I retargeted my project to dotnet 4 and followed your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In 3.5 try using:

```
SmtpClient client = ...

client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

using (MailMessage message = ...)
{
  // where userToken is a user-defined token
  // to be passed to the SendCompletedCallback
  client.SendAsync(message, userToken);
} // Disposes of message
```

Then in the `SendCompletedCallback` trigger the next...

[SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however I re targeted my project to dotnet 4 and did what Ollie jones suggested. Thanks anyway!